# get first insert id for multiple insert using pdo in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have multiple inserts using one query.

Now I am trying to get the first insert id instead of last insert id.

Just wondering if it is at all possible.

My code is

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO answers (quid, answer,catid,qstep,userid) VALUES (:quid,:answer,:catid,:qstep,:userid)";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
foreach ( $insertData as $data )
{
    $query->execute($data);
}
```

Comment: Why not just use auto_increment on `quid` instead of setting one up manually? A lot here...

Comment: sorry quid can't be autoincremented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO answers (quid, answer,catid,qstep,userid) VALUES (:quid,:answer,:catid,:qstep,:userid)";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$firstId = null;
foreach ( $insertData as $data )
{
    $query->execute($data);
    if (null === $firstId)
        $firstId = $this->db->lastInsertId();
}
```

?